# Form and input element looks different on IE11 and Firefox compared to chrome

Tags: html, css

the image of my shopping cart looks different from chrome to IE/firefox. (chrome is straight but IE/FF is positioned slighly lower)

I want them all to look the same as the one in chrome. I am running normalize.css I am quite a newbie programmer so keep that in mind, please can you help me out, below is the html and css:

HTML

```
<li>
    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"     method="post" class="shopping">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="HUUDRV4678LJG">
        <input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">
        <input class="input1"type="image" src="http://asknaturalhealth.com/img/shopping1.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.shopping {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    top: 40px;
    left: 1080px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
}

    .shopping .input1 {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .shopping {
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
        top: 40px;
        left: 1080px;
        margin-left: -1000px;
    }

        .shopping .input1 {
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```